# is there a way to tell if a windows PC is online if I know its IP address?

Tags: windows, networking, security, ip

Is there a way to check if a remote Windows PC (not working as a server, just a personal PC) is online on the internet if I know its IP address?

Comment: Have you tried pinging it? Do you know the PCs public IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, I meant public ip of course, and yes to trying to ping it but it didn't work

Comment: If you don’t have one of the many products that provide a status update, the only way to tell if a machine is up, is to ping or attempt to connect to it

Comment: @Ramhound wdym by attempt to connect, using which protocol?

Comment: If it is behind a NAT router then there may be no way to know if it is online or not without setting up port forwarding first.

Comment: In addition to all the comments and answer, you can tell if it is up, but you cannot tell if it is down... sort of...

Comment: @user1701283 - I have no idea what "wdym" stands for, care to explain, that acronym?  There are third-party products that report the online status of a machine to a centralized server.  You should use one of those products.

Comment: @Ramhound : wdym = what do you mean

Comment: @Bib - There are client software that communicates with server software, which can be accessed remotely and/or locally within a network, to display the status of individual client machines.

Comment: @Ramhound Uhhhh, I was responding to your `I have no idea what "wdym" stands for`. I'm though, well acquainted with such software.

Comment: Can you clearly specify if it's a computer directly exposed on the internet or behind a NAT ?

Comment: @Bib - I was replying to your now clarified "what do you mean, using which protocol?" question from earlier, by indicating there are commercial and open source products that communicate the online status of a client to a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have alluded to this but not spelled it out this clearly:

The public IP address is not to the computer, but is to the modem of that location's internet connection. Knowing it doesn't get you to the computer, just to the most outside point of the home:s internet that, presumably, the computer you want to check is a member of.

Others have mentioned NAT, which basically means you're not getting through on your own.

And then, even if you do get through NAT, there's still the firewall on the modem, on the router (if it's a separate device), and on the computer, and each of these are typically set up not to allow an incoming ping request through.

The simplest thing is to use a utility running on that target computer that reports its up-state to a web site or service you can check.

If you must use ping, you will need to set rules in each of the systems between the target system and you, and some of these are not designed to allow any open doors (NAT, for example).

Comment: You seem to be postulating as universal an arrangement which is merely common for consumer network connections, and conflating multiple cases. There is no hard rule that the public IP has to be that of the modem/router, though that is probably overwhelmingly the case with consumer broadband connections these days. This arrangement typically uses NAT, but you are describing it as if these were two different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows PCs, by default, have the firewall enabled.  So they will not respond to a ping.  If the PC is on an external network (which you have no control over), there may be no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a public IP address it's as simple as pinging it.

If it's behind NAT, forward any open port and try to telnet to this port. There are tons of various ports you can open, e.g. [echo](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2131669-how-can-i-properly-disable-echo-service-in-windows-10) which is pretty safe unlike something like Windows File Sharing (not recommended!!) which has seen a ton of remote exploits.

In both cases firewall has to allow these things.